# Forcing division to be floating-point in Python in a special case

Tags: python, floating-point

This code prints 17, but I want the division to be performed using floating-point (so it should print 17.5 instead).  How can I force the division to be in floating-point?

```
math = 8
physics = 9.5
algebra = 7.50
geometry = 10

**print "My GPA is %d" % ((math + physics + algebra + geometry)/2)**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` is used for integers, for floats use `%f`. Using `%d` for floats will print only it's decimal part.

```
>>> print "My GPA is %f" % ((math + physics + algebra + geometry)/2)
My GPA is 17.500000
```

or:

```
>>> print "My GPA is %.1f" % ((math + physics + algebra + geometry)/2)
My GPA is 17.5
```

Using new style string formatting:

```
>>> print "My GPA is {:.1f}" .format((math + physics + algebra + geometry)/2)
My GPA is 17.5
```

Also note that integer division in py2.x truncates the output and returns an integer.

To fix that you should convert at least one of the operand to float.

```
>>> 3/2
1
>>> 3/float(2)
1.5
>>> 3/2.
1.5
```

or import python3.x's `divison`:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning `from __future__ import division` in case all the scores are integers and the OP is using Python 2.x.